# Changing of basis from conjugate diagonal to rotation matrix

Tags: linear-algebra

Given matrices,
$$D = \begin{pmatrix}
z & 0 \\
0 & \bar{z}
\end{pmatrix}, \hspace{12pt}
B = \begin{pmatrix}
1 & -i \\
1 & i
\end{pmatrix}, \hspace{12pt}
U = \begin{pmatrix}
Re(z)& Im(z) \\
-Im(z) & Re(z)
\end{pmatrix}$$
the change of basis given by $B$ results in
$U = B^{-1} D B$.

Of course, I can do the computations and verify this. But what's really going on here? Is there something geometric in this change of basis that allows me to decompose $z$ into its real and imaginary parts? Is the fact that $U$ is a rotation matrix relevant?